# User unable to search for accounts via soql

Tags: apex, content-search

I'm using a visualforce page to search an account number where User will able to search a group by leading “0” in addition to 5 alpha-numeric values.

If leading “0” is not entered, system should return the result using 5 alpha-numeric values entered. I have written a SOQL query to find the matching records.

For example if an account number is like 12345, and a user tries to search it with 012345 then the results should be returned same as like 12345

```
 if(!String.isEmpty(SearchNum))
      {
      SearchGrpNum = '\'%' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(SearchNum.trim()) + '%\'';
      whereClause += 'Accountnumber like' +SearchNum ;            
      }
String query = 'select id,AccountNumber,Name from account where +whereClause';
```

How can I implement this?

Comment: Your question is not very clear, what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: Does changing your `String query` to `'select id,AccountNumber,Name from account where' + whereClause;` solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

1) There are spaces needed where you are creating `whereClause` string.

2) At the end of `query` string `whereClause` will be outside of hard coded string.

The correct format will be like this:

```
if(!String.isEmpty(SearchNum))
 {
      SearchGrpNum = '\'%' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(SearchNum.trim()) + '%\'';
      whereClause += ' Accountnumber like ' +SearchNum ;            
 }
String query = 'SELECT id,AccountNumber,Name FROM account where ' + whereClause;
```